# Find First and Last Position of Element in Sorted Array in the order of O(log n)

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, time-complexity

I am doing leetcode #34

https://leetcode.com/problems/find-first-and-last-position-of-element-in-sorted-array/

Given an array of integers nums sorted in ascending order, find the starting and ending position of a given target value.

Your algorithm's runtime complexity must be in the order of O(log n).

If the target is not found in the array, return [-1, -1].

Example 1:

Input: nums = [5,7,7,8,8,10], target = 8
Output: [3,4]

Example 2:

Input: nums = [5,7,7,8,8,10], target = 6
Output: [-1,-1]

```js
var searchRange = function(nums, target) {
  var result = [];
  result[0] = findFirstIndex(nums, target);
  result[1] = findLastIndex(nums, target);

  return result;
};
//[5,7,7,8,8,10], target=10, midpoint=3
function findFirstIndex(nums, target) {
  var index = -1; //if cant find, return index=-1, will not execute below action
  var start = 0;
  var end = nums.length - 1;
  while (start <= end) {
    var midPoint = start + (end - start) / 2;
    if (nums[midPoint] >= target) {
      end = midPoint - 1;
    } else {
      start = midPoint + 1;
    }

    if (nums[midPoint] === target) {
      index = midPoint;
    }
  }
  return index;
}

function findLastIndex(nums, target) {
  var index = -1;
  var start = 0;
  var end = nums.length - 1;
  while (start <= end) {
    var midPoint = start + (end - start) / 2;
    if (nums[midPoint] <= target) {
      start = midPoint + 1; //[start,end]=[0,2]
    } else {
      end = midPoint - 1;
    }

    if (nums[midPoint] === target) {
      index = midPoint;
    }
  }
  return index;
}
```

Actually this answer I am reference Nick white 's method in Java way. I think the concept should be correct but still can not execute the answer.

Can anyone know why? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to round `midPoint` down to an integer, otherwise you'll try to access fractional indexes.

```js
var searchRange = function(nums, target) {
  var result = [];
  result[0] = findFirstIndex(nums, target);
  result[1] = findLastIndex(nums, target);

  return result;
};

console.log(searchRange([5,7,8,8,8,10], 8));
console.log(searchRange([5,7,8,8,8,10], 10));

function findFirstIndex(nums, target) {
  var index = -1; //if cant find, return index=-1, will not execute below action
  var start = 0;
  var end = nums.length - 1;
  while (start <= end) {
    var midPoint = Math.floor(start + (end - start) / 2);
    if (nums[midPoint] >= target) {
      end = midPoint - 1;
    } else {
      start = midPoint + 1;
    }

    if (nums[midPoint] === target) {
      index = midPoint;
    }
  }
  return index;
}

function findLastIndex(nums, target) {
  var index = -1;
  var start = 0;
  var end = nums.length - 1;
  while (start <= end) {
    var midPoint = Math.floor(start + (end - start) / 2);
    if (nums[midPoint] <= target) {
      start = midPoint + 1; //[start,end]=[0,2]
    } else {
      end = midPoint - 1;
    }

    if (nums[midPoint] === target) {
      index = midPoint;
    }
  }
  return index;
}
```

Comment: Yes! It works. Thanks for your prompt and accurate answer

Comment: If you simply put `console.log(midPoint)` in the loop you might have figured this out yourself.

Comment: Yes. there is chance for the array length is in even number.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no need for `findLastIndex` method. I modified a bit the solution of @Barmar.

```
    var searchRange = function(nums, target) {
    if(nums.length == 0) return [-1,-1];
    var result = [];
    var index = findFirstIndex(nums, target);
    result[0] = index;
    var value = nums[index];

    while(nums[index] === value){index++}

    result[1] = index - 1;

    return result;
};
```

With this approach, I got `48 ms, faster than 96.65% of JavaScript online submissions`.

It will not improve overall `Big O` complexity but surely it will improve `average-case` complexity.

Comment: This makes it O(n) in worst case. Consider an array with all equal values.

Comment: @vivek_23, yes and as I said it will improve `average-case` complexity.

Comment: It does not improve the average case complexity at all; the complexity in the average case is still O(log n). It may improve the actual running time, but that is not what "complexity" means.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to solve this.

```
   public int[] searchRange(int[] nums, int target) {

          int[] ans = {-1, -1};

        ans[0] = findFirstAndLastPosition(nums, target, true);
        if (ans[0] != -1) {
            ans[1] = findFirstAndLastPosition(nums, target, false);
        }

        return ans;
    }

    int findFirstAndLastPosition(int[] arr, int target, boolean isFindFirstIndext) {

        int l = 0;
        int r = arr.length -1;
        int m = 0;
        int ans = -1;

        while (l <= r) {
            m = l + (r - l) /2;    
            if (target > arr[m]) {
                l = m + 1;
            }else if (target < arr[m]) {
                r = m -1 ;
            }else {
                ans = m;
                if (isFindFirstIndext) {
                    r = m-1;
                  }else {
                    l = m+1;
                  }
            }
        }

        return ans;
    }
```